# Подключить .js через тэг script Post запросом

Tags: javascript, html

День добрый.
Проблема заключается в том,что для каждого пользователя генерируется своя js,которую возможно подключить только Post запросом. 
Пример запроса:

```
POST /javascript.js HTTP/1.1
Host: <SITE>
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie: <cookie>

user=54652
```

Как мне подключить эту js,через тэг script?

Comment: Никак. Тег script работает только get-ом

Comment: @AlexeyTen, почему не ответом?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй получить строку JS кода и вставить в `eval` 
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval